# Error "dotnet : Could not find any project in `C:\**." when running "dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount"

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have visual studio 2019 and i created a new asp.net core 2.2 project. now i am following these steps [Configure Microsoft Account Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configure-microsoft-account-authentication) to enable external login to our web application. but when i run this command:-

> dotnet add package
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount

i got this error:-

> PM> dotnet add package
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount dotnet : Could
>   not find any project in `C:\Users\*****\source\repos\MSlogintest\`. At
>   line:1 char:1
>   + dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Could not find ...\MSlogintest`.:String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError   Usage: dotnet add  package [options]
>
> Arguments:           The project file to operate on. If a
>   file is not specified, the command will search the current directory
>   for one.      The package reference to add.
>
> Options:   -h, --help                          Show command line help.
>   -v, --version              The version of the package to add.   -f, --framework          Add the reference only when targeting a specific framework.   -n, --no-restore
>   Add the reference without performing restore preview and compatibility
>   check.   -s, --source                The NuGet package source
>   to use during the restore.   --package-directory    The
>   directory to restore packages to.   --interactive
>   Allows the command to stop and wait for user input or action (for
>   example to complete authentication).

as follow:-
[image]

and when i access the folder, i found that there is a VS project folders, as follow:-
[image]

so why the error is saying that it can not find any project?
can anyone advice on this error please?
Thanks

Comment: You're in the solution folder, not the project folder. Drop a level lower (e.g. `cd MSlogintest`) and try again.

Comment: Either that or `dotnet add MSlogintest package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount`, which provides the project name before `package`.

Comment: @DavidG do you mean i need to run `cd MSlogintest` inside the Nuget command-line ? i have never chnage directory inside Nuget command line... and why this is not mentioned in the official MS documentation link

Comment: @KirkLarkin can you explain what do u mean by `Either that or dotnet add MSlogintest package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount, which provides the project name before package`?

Comment: @KirkLarkin i run this command `PM> dotnet add MSlogintest package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount` but i got this error `dotnet : Could not find project or directory `MSlogintest`.`

Comment: It should work if you're doing that from the same location as shown in your screenshot. If you did the suggested `cd MSlogintest` first, you'll need to use your original `dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount` command.

Comment: Unless the project name isn't `MSlogintest` but only you can determine that.

Comment: @KirkLarkin yes this works for me now i run `cd MSlogintest ` then `dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount` and it worked fine... do you think that the MS link should mentioned this? as they just said to open Nuget then run the command..

Comment: I think you're mixing two sets of instructions from the docs. It says either use the built-in "Manage NuGet Packages" *or* the ".NET Core CLI". It also states *execute the following in your project directory*, but I can see why that might be a little confusing. If you feel strongly, you can raise an issue on the docs page itself.

Answer (score 40):

I encountered the same issue and found the fix. First of all, read the error message completely and carefully. It says:

"Could not find any project ...."

Which means it was expecting the project information. If you further watch the message closely, it has mentioned the correct usage of this command i.e.

Usage: dotnet add <PROJECT> package [options] <PACKAGE_NAME>

In the  argument, enter your project name and run it again. This time, you should see the success message similar to:

info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Microsoft.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx' into project 'C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\ProjectFolder\xxxxxxxx.csproj'.

[image: demonstration of the error and the fix]

Comment: This answer (and the error message) seems to indicate that "dotnet add" somehow wants to add a library to a project. This does not make sense to me - I want to add a library globally.

Comment: The project should be in .csproj. If you have .sln, open it using a text editor and find the .csproj

Answer (score 17):

Got this working on powershell (no IDE). The solution was somewhere hidden in the comments but here is the easy one:

`dotnet add <project> package <packageName>`

In this case I believe it would be:

`dotnet add ContosoUniversity package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount`

Comment: Solved by following above instructions

Comment: Kinda weird how this project thing is not implicitly applied when the command is run within the project dir.

Answer (score 9):

cd into the particular project you want to add the package to and type your dotnet command again

```
> cd project Directory
> dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount
```

Answer (score 2):

This command is for .NET core. I used it for an old project because it's the first one shown on nuget.org.

The old command should be like this:

```
Install-Package [package name]
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, when i was fiddling around with the nuget commandline it at some point proposed i should retry with elevated privileges.
Specifically i tried manually pointing it one level deeper in the folder structure. (As suggested by DavidG)

I thought: okay, weird, but i am out of good ideas, so lets try that one.

Restarted as administrator, worked.

And by it worked i mean it just worked, no manual fiddling involved. I just used the graphical package manager option that just somehow became available.

So my best guess is i somehow messed up something when installing visual studio. Because i already tried just creating a new project.

[Nuget option as admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3X0A.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may be clicking on the wrong tab on the nuget site. Make sure you select Package Manager tab. The error you get happens when you click on the .net cli tab and use it in the package manager console window.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your command terminal, you should into a directory project:

dotnet add  package <package.name>

Answer (score 0):

First, go the settings as marked.

[image: Screenshot]

Then add the source as mentioned:

[image: Screenshot]

These will definitely solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For MacBook on VSCode, it is the same way, e.g:

```
dotnet add youprojectname package Dapper --version 2.1.35
```